# Sphinx not generating documentation for file

Tags: python, python-sphinx

So I am generating documentation using Sphinx and one of the files is not displaying. It is the `PyTuner tuner` in the image.

The file has 3 classes in a numpydoc configuration.

Here is `source/conf.py`:

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'PyTuner'
copyright = '2021, Vedant Mehta'
author = 'Vedant Mehta'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '1.0.0'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autosummary','numpydoc','rinoh.frontend.sphinx', 'sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ,'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Here is `source/index.rst`:

```
.. PyTuner documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon Feb 22 22:45:17 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to PyTuner's documentation!
===================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



PyTuner tuner 
=====================
.. autoclass:: tuner.tuner
   :members:
PyTuner tunertools
=====================
.. automodule:: tuner.tunertools
   :members:

PyTuner dropdown
===================
.. automodule:: tuner.dropdown
   :members:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

[image: Tuner file not generating]

Comment: Add a blank line before "PyTuner tunertools".

Comment: @mzjn that still gains the same output.

Comment: Are there any warnings or error messages when you run Sphinx?

Comment: You should probably not use both numpydoc and sphinx.ext.napoleon at the same time.

Comment: @mzjn thank you so much! It looks like numpydoc may have been overriding something in napoleon. Post this as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extensions` configuration contains both `numpydoc` and `sphinx.ext.napoleon`.

I don't know the exact cause of your problem, but these extensions are quite similar and you should use only one of them.

And there should be a blank line before "PyTuner tunertools".